# Folders hidden under subfolder? How to restore back?

Tags: dual-boot, nautilus, directory

I have a Windows partition, let's call it WIN and under it I have Folder1 and Folder2.
So in other words a "ls" on /media/myUser/WIN would show the two folders
My problem is that for a couple of days something happened and now I can't see Folder2 at all. I only see Folder1. I am tempted to say it was deleted or moved, however when I go to Folder1 and inside I go to Subfolder1 and then I go to open another subsub folder I just see my entire WIN disk with both my Folder1 and Folder2 as they should be.

What I expect is

```
WIN
   Folder1
   Folder2
```

What I get is

```
WIN
   Folder1
      SubFolder1
         WIN 
           Folder1
           Folder2
```

It is as if the WIN drive was mounted somehow partially or backwards or something.

Does anyone have any idea about how to restore and mount correctly my WIN drive so I can see both Folder1 and Folder2 from the beginning?

Ubuntu is 18.04 and I use Double Commander or Nautilus to browse

Comment: The notation you've used is very confusing. How can "Folder1" be in a directory that contains "Folder1"?  `ls -a` will show all files including hidden files and directories.  From that command you should be able to determine where your files are located.  A file system cannot be mounted "partially or backwards".

Comment: Have the file system of your window partition checked using the tools in MS Windows.

Comment: @Nmath: yes, that is what I have. So weird to have a cyclic reference...

Comment: @vanadium: yes, that seems to be the problem. I tried to log on Windows and I can't. The disk is corrupt. So I think you are 100% correct, now I need to backup my data from it and format it. It is a long overdue task, now I am motivate-bligated to do so. Thanks!